# Move Letter Pressed from an Input to Another

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I get a letter pressed from an input and move that letter to another input using jquery? But I want it to MOVE to another, not COPY or something like that. REMOVE from original input and PLACE in another.

For example:

```
<input id="txt1" type="text">
<input id="txt2" type="text">
<script>
  $('#txt1').on('input', function(evt) {
    //get key pressed (txt1) and move to another input (txt2)
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to append the input of `#txt1` to the value of the second one, and then keep the initial value only:

```js
let len = $('#txt1').val().length;
$('#txt1').on('input', function(evt) {
    if($(this).val().length < len){ //delete
         len = $(this).val().length;
         return;
    }
    let val1 = $(this).val();
    if(val1.length > 1) 
         val1 = val1.charAt(val1.length-1);
    let val2 = $('#txt2').val();
    $('#txt2').val(val2 + val1);
    len = $(this).val().length-1;
    $(this).val( $(this).val().substring(0,len) );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="txt1" type="text" value="hello">
<input id="txt2" type="text">
```

Comment: excellent, it works.. but now I have another question.. what if the original input already has some value, I press another key and I want only this last key pressed to be moved to the other input, not everything in original input?

Comment: @Andre I added this case to the answer. Do you want the initial value to be removed or keep it?

Comment: I want to keep the initial value, just move the last char added

Comment: @Andre I updated the answer. Removal from the initial value do not affect the addition as well.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest is use `val(function)` which exposes the current value in it's callback

```js
$('#txt1').on('input', function(evt) {    
    $('#txt2').val((_, v) => v + this.value);
    this.value = '';
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="txt1" type="text" value="hello">
<input id="txt2" type="text">
```